# adjust UITableViewCell height according to the content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

content of the cell is hiding. I tried to increase the height of cell but its not working.

[When I am running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aIP5.png)

[In my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olZu1.png)

I tried:

```
 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and also tried

```
self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
```

self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

Please help me to figure out what's wrong

Comment: Do you really need dynamic cell height? If no, just return 80 in `heightForRow` method.

Comment: yes, I need dynamic cell height. Thanks

Comment: If you need dynamic height then use your first option i.e 
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension but after providing correct AutoLayout constraints to you views inside the cell.

Comment: Also implement heightForRowAt method of tableView if you think your constraints are proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your vertical constraints for labels. You need to set fixed spacing between the following:

1. Top & Label1
2. Label1 & Label2
3. Label2 & Label3
4. Label3 & Bottom

This way all three labels will have dynamic height and cell will have appropriate height as well.